# How to get Key Value Pair value from valid JSON string in PowerApps?

Tags: power-automate, json, powerapps-canvas

I am working with the requirement in PowerApps where I have a JSON string like below

```
{
  "Created": "2022-08-29T16:40:19",
  "IsCurrentVersion": true,
  "VersionId": 8192,
  "VersionLabel": "16.0",
  "Title": "Test Title",
  "Position": "Developer"
}
```

Now I need to fetch the values from this string in PowerApps.

I have gone through [Introduction to Parse JSON in Power Apps | ParseJSON Arrays as Table; Return Array from flow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqfLiJDdC3Q)
video, but here we need to specify the key name to get the value.

Also, I do not know what will be Key & Values in my JSON string.

I want to know whether it is possible to iterate through all key value pair dynamically and get the values.

Comment: ParseJSON function returns untyped object. So, I don't think you will be able to dynamically read keys from object using ParseJSON. You may need to try another approach for reading keys.

Comment: Yes looking for some working approach and that's why the question is added here. May be someone has some idea on that.